# file upload angular - spring boot - mysql

Tags: mysql, angular, spring-boot

I had a working post api sending formdata to the back end and posting it to the DB .
when I added an input file type to the form and appended it the dataform, I got errors.

I always have this error:

> "error: "Internal Server Error"
>   message: "Unrecognized field "file" (class org.sid.model.User), not marked as ignorable (6 known properties: "fileName", "id", "email", "name", "password", "logo"])↵ at [Source: (String)"{"name":"ss","email":"sss","password":"ssssssss","file":"C:\fakepath\ooredoo_758118.png"}"; line: 1, column: 58] (through reference chain: org.sid.model.User["file"])"
>   path: "/users"
>   "

**Controller**

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = { "http://localhost:4200", "http://localhost:9000" }, maxAge = 36000)
/*@RequestMapping(value="/users" , method=RequestMethod.POST)*/
@RequestMapping(value="/users" , headers = ("content-type=multipart/*"), method = RequestMethod.POST,
consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE ,
        produces = { "application/json" }
)
public User save(@RequestPart("file") MultipartFile f  ,
        @RequestPart ("user") String u) 
        throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException{
    User user = new ObjectMapper().readValue(u, User.class) ;
    user.setLogo(f.getBytes());
    return userRepository.save(user);

    }
```

**User.java**

```
@Entity
public class User { 
@Id @GeneratedValue
private Long id ;
private String name ;
private String email ;
private String password ;
@Column(name="logo")
private byte[] logo;
@Column(name="file_name")
private String fileName ;
```

}

**mainApplication.java**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyChebbaApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyChebbaApplication.class, args);
    }   
    @Bean
    public MultipartConfigElement multipartConfigElement() {
        MultipartConfigFactory factory = new MultipartConfigFactory();
        factory.setMaxFileSize("10240KB");
        factory.setMaxRequestSize("10240KB");
        return factory.createMultipartConfig();
    }


}
```

**Clien Side**

**component.html**

```
 <div class="container" >
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading">Register</div>
          <div class="panel-body">
              <form class="form-horizontal" #form="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(form)">

                  <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="name" class="control-label col-md-4">Nom Complet</label>

                      <div class="col-md-6">
                        <input id="name" type="text" name="name" #userName="ngModel" ngModel class="form-control" required>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="email" class="control-label col-md-4">E-mail Address</label>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                          <input id="email" type="email" name="email" #userEmail="ngModel" ngModel class="form-control" required>
                        </div>
                      </div>


                      <!-- <div class="form-group">
                          <label for="phone" class="control-label col-md-4">Phone number</label>

                          <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input id="phone" type="phone" name="phone" #phone="ngModel" ngModel class="form-control" >
                          </div>
                        </div> -->


                      <div class="form-group">
                          <label for="password" class="control-label col-md-4">Password</label>

                          <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input id="password" type="text" name="password" #password="ngModel" ngModel class="form-control" required>
                          </div>
                        </div>

                      <div class="form-group">
                          <label for="file" class="control-label col-md-4">File Upload</label>

                          <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input 
                             type="file" 
                            name="file"  
                            accept="image/*"
                            (change)="onFileSelected($event)" 
                            ngModel class="form-control" >
                          </div>
                        </div>              

                  <div class="form-group">
                          <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-4">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"
                              [disabled]="form.invalid">
                              Register
                            </button>
                          </div>
                        </div>



              </form>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

**component.ts**

```
    selectedFile: File = null ;


  constructor(private userService: UserService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

onFileSelected(event) {
  console.log(event) ;
this.selectedFile = event.target.files[0] ;
}


  onSubmit(form: any) {
    let fd = new FormData() ;
    const user = form.value ;
    fd.append('user' , JSON.stringify(user)) ;
    fd.append('file' , this.selectedFile ) ;
    console.log(fd) ;
    this.userService.register(fd  )
      .then((resp) => {
        this.userService.logUserIn(resp) ;
      }) ;
  }
```

**user.service.ts**

```
   register(fd: FormData ): Promise<UserData> {
    return this.http.post(`${CONFIG.API_URL}/users`, fd)
                    .toPromise()
                    .then((response) => {
                        let token = response.json().token ;
                            let user = response.json() ;

                            let userData = new UserData(token, user) ;
                            this.router.navigate(['/users']);
                            return userData ;
                    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

this means that your JSON String u doesn't contain "file" field. In order to ignore missing fields please use this:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper()
                      .configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false) 

mapper.readValue(u, User.class);
```

...

Good luck.

Comment: i did that and hrows me this error :  "com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Data too long for column 'logo' at row 1 "

Answer (score 0):

It means that **User** doesn't have a property **file**.

To solve that, just disable that config in **applicatgion.properties**.

```
pring.jackson.deserialization.fail-on-unknown-properties=true
```

Comment: i added it , but stil the same error . unrecognised field file